# Solr query not working

Tags: apache, solr, full-text-search, search-engine

I am using Solr for the first time to integrate my mobile app with Stubhub API. If you run this query in a browser, it runs fine:

```
http://www.stubhub.com/listingCatalog/select?q=+stubhubDocumentType:event%20AND%20city:seattle%20AND%20event_date:[NOW%20TO%20*]%20AND%20NOT%20totalTickets:0%20AND%20active:1;event_date_time_local%20asc%20&start=0&rows=50&fl=genreId+description%20event_id%20event_date_time_local channel
```

Notice that this query has a parameter for event_date which looks like this:

```
event_date:[NOW%20TO%20*] // '%20' is just the SPACE character
```

Instead of searching for everything from NOW to indefinitely in the future, when I want to search for only the current and next, I change the parameter as follows:

```
event_date:[NOW TO NOW/DAY+1DAY]
```

Doing this, the query does not work anymore. You can try it first hand in a browser yourself. What am I missing?

Comment: General tip: never give out your Server URL in your questions. Someone may simply run a delete all query for fun, unless you have security set up.

Comment: Hi Arun, this is a public URL and available in stubhub API documentation. So, there is no security risk as you state.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is simple. Just URL encode your `+` to `%2B` i.e. change

```
event_date:[NOW TO NOW/DAY+1DAY]
```

to

```
event_date:[NOW%20TO%20NOW/DAY%2B1DAY]
```

Comment: that doesn't help arun. you can try it yourself in a browser, if you would.

Comment: 1DAY does not return any docs but the query works. Try 10DAY http://www.stubhub.com/listingCatalog/select?q=+stubhubDocumentType:event%20AND%20city:seattle%20AND%20event_date:[NOW%20TO%20NOW/DAY%2B10DAY]%20AND%20NOT%20totalTickets:0%20AND%20active:1;event_date_time_local%20asc%20&start=0&rows=50&fl=genreId+description%20event_id%20event_date_time_local%20channel

Answer (score 0):

My query was fine only that therewas no data for 1 day. So, when I increased my time range from 1 day to 10 days, it worked! Stupid me. :P